# Angular: Data undefined while subscribing to the observable

Tags: angular

I am making an HTTP request to a backend and fetching the data in my main app service. I am extending that observable by mapping it in my contacts service and subscribing to it in my contacts component. However, I am getting an issue while doing so. The data is printed as undefined.

Here's my code:

> app.service.ts

```
postHTTPRequest(url: string, tokenValue: string) : Observable<any>
{
  return this.http.post(this.baseURL + url, {token: tokenValue});
}
```

> contacts.service.ts

```
getData() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue).pipe(map(response => {
      console.log("Printing in contacts service " + response);
  }))
}
```

> contacts.component.ts

```
getData()
{
  this.contactsService.getData().subscribe(response => {
    console.log("Printing in the component " + response);
  })
}
```

I am getting this on console `Printing in the component undefined`. The service part is printing totally fine. Help. Thanks!

Comment: return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue).pipe(map(response => {
return response ;
  }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `pipe` & `map` so it must return value in your map function so you need to update your code like below.

```
getData() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue).pipe(map(response => {
      console.log("Printing in contacts service " + response);
      return response;
  }))
}
```

once you return your response you will get the same data on your subscribed method.

If you are not changing your response data and simply returning it then you can simply write return without `pipe` & `map` functions.

**Sample:**

```
getData() : Observable<any>
{
   return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue);
}
```

**Edit:** One more suggestion for code optimization you can either omit `contacts.service.ts` or you can directly call your API in the contact service without `app.service.ts` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `contacts.service.ts` you `map` the response to `undefined`, because there is no actual return value.

Change it from

```
getData() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue).pipe(map(response => {
      console.log("Printing in contacts service " + response);
  }))
}
```

to

```
getData() : Observable<any>
{
  return this.appService.postHTTPRequest(this.contactsURL, this.tokenValue).pipe(map(response => {
      console.log("Printing in contacts service " + response);
      return response;
  }))
}
```